# Python/Scrapy: Callback function never calls

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am using scrapy to crawl google play items profiles but callback function is not executed. I can't find problem in code (no errors). Can you tell me any solution?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

import time

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from playcrawl.items import PlaycrawlItem
from scrapy.http import Request

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractor import LinkExtractor

class GoogleplaySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'googleplay'
    allowed_domains = ['play.google.com']
    start_urls = ['https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/GAME']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/store/apps'))),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/store/apps/details\?')),callback="parse_item")
        )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        item = PlaycrawlItem()
        item["pub"] = hxs.select('//a[@class = "document-subtitle primary"]/span[1]').select("text()").extract()
        item["email"] = hxs.select('//a[contains(@class, "dev-link") and starts-with(@href, "mailto")]').select("@href").extract()[0][7:]

        f = open("D:\\_scrapy\\playcrawl\\data_emails.txt", "a")
        f.write(item["email"] + "\n")
        f.close()

        print("\n\n\n\n" + item["email"] + "\n\n\n\n")
        time.sleep(0)

        return item #yield item
```

Comment: Can you please try by adding `follow=True` in the rules?

Comment: The tag should be `python-3.x` instead of `python-2.7`

Comment: why python 3.x?

Comment: follow=True is default value and I try it already

Comment: try `'.*/store/apps/details\?'` since it's supposed to match absolute URL

Comment: @Fabricator still not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code, and the reason is easy.

The spider just hasn't matched the second `Rule`.

Try this:

```
rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/store/apps')),callback="parse_item"),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/store/apps/details\?')),callback="parse_item")
        )
```

And then it works, so there is no bug about your code but about your logic.